# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in swift

Tags: swift

I am new at Swift. I want to detect device is rotating (portrait or Landscape). And of course I need that in Swift.
Objective C code:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(detectOrientation)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil]; 

-(void) detectOrientation {
    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        [self doLandscapeThings];
    } else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self doPortraitThings];
    }   
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect rotation you can implement these two methods:

```
    override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    }

    override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    }
```

Translating that code into swift is something you're gonna have to try yourself, with a basic knowledge of swift that shouldn't be a problem. If you have specific issues, you can always post them here on SO, but we can't do your homework for you :-)

(Hint: this is one line of your code:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft {

}
```

)